# How to send form data from extjs grid with rendered column input field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a ExtJs Form Panel

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        forceFit: true,
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
        collapsible: true,
        store: duplicateDataStore,
        title: 'Data (' + duplicateDataStore.getCount() + ')',
        columns: [
            this.getRadioButton()
        ]
    }]
}
```

...

```
getRadioButton: function() {
    return {
        header: 'name',
        hideable: false,
        renderer: this.renderRadioBox,
        formBind: true
    };
},

renderRadioBox: function( val, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store ) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" role="checkbox" name="test" value="1" >';
},
```

After clicking the submit button i select the current form values.

```
this.lookupReference( 'data' ).down( 'form' ).getForm().getValues();
```

But i could not get any data from this selection. When i add a checkbox-item to the form, data will be readable, but not from the grid column.

Is there a solution for it?

Comment: What Ext Version are you using?

Comment: I use version 5.1.0 of extjs

Comment: Send me complete here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home so that i can find issue easily.

Comment: are there some examples for this usecase? I think i need too much time, to build this in sencha-fiddle, so i use the click listener on the checkbox, to update data.